# How to convert .xlsx file in R to .xls

Tags: r, xlsx, xls, r-rio

I have specific need- one of the uploads I need to do is allowed only in `.xls` file.

So I am reading input in R (input is in `.xlsx`) via following command:

```
library(rio);
Data= import("Table.xlsx",skip=1);
```

Now this Data is a dataframe in R. I want to save this in .xls format. However, package rio does not allow it via following command:

```
export((Data),"Table.xls"); #This command fails as rio does not support .xls
```

So question is- how do I store (export) my `.xlsx` file as `.xls`?

Any new library that can do this task?

Any new library or libraries are fine

Comment: The legacy .xls format is not well supported by R packages in general, or at least not obviously so, but just typing your query into google leads to the Writexls package.  Try that.

Comment: The xlsx R package (R interface to java software) and the WriteXLS R package (R interface to perl software) can write xls files. There are also non-R solutions. Libre Office has a command line utility soffice which can convert xlsx to xls. You can read an xlsx file into Excel and save it as xls.

Comment: Paul and G. Grothendieck-  Thanks for your help. WriteXLS package in R need java, so does this mean I need to execute the code outside RStudio? I am getting error in my mac using this package. Libre Office can be the easy solution to my problem though, thanks for the suggestion.